# Service stops in android version Oreo and app crashes

Tags: java, android

Service stops in android version Oreo and app crashes. Please guys help me to resolve this problem. 
When I am trying to add `startServiceForeground()`, then it is crashing I have no idea what is going on, so help me.

```
//Start Service method
private void startSipService() {      
    Thread t = new Thread("StartSip") {
        public void run() {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(SipHome.this,SipService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(SipManager.EXTRA_OUTGOING_ACTIVITY,
                new ComponentName(SipHome.this, SipHome.class));
            startService(serviceIntent);z
            if(user==null||user==""){
                postStartSipService();
            }
            //                boolean status;
            //                status = loginStatus();
            //                if (!status){}
            //               postStartSipService();
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Could you add the logcat error, please?

Comment: no eroor coming out in logcat service stop itself in oreo version

Comment: when you start foreground service but your app is backgrounded, the service will stop after 5 seconds, unless you have a permanent notification attached to it.

Comment: i m in foreground in app when using foregroundservice() but app crash

Comment: if the app crashes you should be getting a stacktrace error. It would help if we got more details on that error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Intent myService = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(myService);
    } else {
        startService(myService);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 8.0 (API level 26) also includes the following changes to specific methods:  The `startService()` method now throws an 
 `IllegalStateException` if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.

The new `Context.startForegroundService()` method starts a foreground service. The system allows apps to call `Context.startForegroundService()` even while the app is in the background. However, the app must call that service's `startForeground()` method within five seconds after the service is created.  For more information, see [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).